# Warped product semi-slant submanifolds in Kenmotsu

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

For any nonzero vector $Z$ tangent to $M$ we have

$\phi Z = tZ + nZ$

And for any vector $V$ normal to $M$ we have

$\phi V = BV + CV$

Given that ${M= N_\theta \times _f N_T}$. 
Where $N_\theta$ is a proper slant submanifold of $M$, $N_T$ is an invariant submanifold of $M$ and $\xi$ is tangent to $M$.

And $X,Y \in \Gamma(TN_\theta)$ and $U,V \in \Gamma (TN_T)$

Using $(\bar\nabla_X \phi)U = \bar\nabla_X \phi U  - \phi(\bar\nabla_X U)$

How do we arrive at

$g(\phi X,U)\xi - \eta(U)\phi X = h(X, tU) - Bh(X,U) - Ch(X,U)$

I am trying to follow a proof in one of the papers by $At\acute{c}eken$ but I get lost on the way as some terms do not completely cancel out

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Using $(\bar\nabla_X \phi)U = \bar\nabla_X \phi U  - \phi(\bar\nabla_X U)$

I got  $(\bar\nabla_X \phi)U = \bar\nabla_X \phi U  - \phi(\nabla_X U + h(X,U))$

                                            $= \nabla_X  t U  + h(X,U) - \phi \nabla_X U -B h(X,U) - Ch(X,U)$
                                           $ = \nabla_X  tU - [ \nabla_X  \phi U - (\nabla_ X \phi U ] + h(X,U)  -B h(X,U) - Ch(X,U)$

                                          $ = \nabla_X  tU - \nabla_X   tU + (\nabla_ X \phi) U  + h(X,U)  -B h(X,U) - Ch(X,U)$

The  $  (\nabla_ X \phi ) U $ remains. That is what I get